# slimming the Ektron workarea

Tags: content-management-system, ektron

We have replicated our base Ektron site over 100 times (different clients) and between copies on the web servers and putting sites in SVN, I have decided to pull out the scalpel and slim down the workarea.

Folders that I find take up the most space:

- \Help
- \Documentation
- \eWebEditPRo
- \eWebDiff
- \Foundation\RadControls\Spell\TDF (lots of unneeded language files)

Has anyone done this and what have you cut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of ektron (v8.5) supports a true 3-tier architecture. This is relevant to your situation because it would allow you to have a single full Ektron installation on the middle-tier (application server), and have a very minimal configuration on the front-end (presentation server). The minimal configuration on the presentation server would not require you to have *any* workarea folder, nor would it require *all* of the DLLs in the bin folder. Ultimately it gives you great control over what you place on your front-end presentation server.

I have a webinar on this exact configuration coming out on 9/15/2011. It will cover installation, configuration, the developer experience, best practices, etc. If you're interested, keep an eye on this page http://www.ektron.com/Resources/Webinars/. If you visit this link after 9/15/2011, the webinar should be recorded, archived, and available on that page.

Comment: Thanks.  I will definitely check it out.

Comment: Here's the URL to the 3-tier webinar, it's happening this coming Thursday (9/29/2011): http://www.ektron.com/webinars/3_tier_architecture/

Comment: Here's the recorded webinar on 3-tier: http://www.ektron.com/Resources-And-Tools/Webinars/Screencasts/Technical/The-3-Tier-Architecture/ Also, I have second webinar on 3-tier coming up next month (this second one will be more advanced), you can sign up for it here: http://www.ektron.com/News-And-Events/Developer-Newsletter/

Comment: Here a second recorded webinar on 3-tier, this one is more advanced, discusses building a middle-tier service layer. For your orignal question (slimming down the workarea), the first webinar is probably enough, but if you're interested in 3-tier, make sure to watch both http://ektron.com/Resources-And-Tools/Webinars/Screencasts/Advanced-Development-in-a-3-Tier-Environment/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the GeoIP files in App_Data, especially if you're not using any geolocation.

(GeoIPOrg.dat ~140MB, GeoLitCity.dat ~30MB, GeoIPDomain.dat ~5MB)